# vercel reserved environment variables (aws S3)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, deployment, vercel

When deploying on vercel (free tier), the following is shown if aws S3 env vars are added to the project:

`Error:The name of your Environment Variable is reserved. Please choose another name. Learn More`

the link pointing to:

https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/limits/overview?query=reserve#reserved-variables

Deployment fails; how can these variables be set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change var names to something else so they don't clash with those defined on vercel.